# Adding text (eg: image source) at the bottom right of a figure

Tags: floats

I want to add text (i.e the image source), which includes a citation, at the bottom right of a figure like this:

[image: figure with source]

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
\begin{figure}[h]   
\center{\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{merit_order}}  
{\small{\raggedleft{test \cite{_some_citation_}}}       %this does not work    
\caption{Merit-order of generating plants}  
\label{fig:meritorder}  
\end{figure}
```

which produces this result:

[image: figure latex no source]

I have tried several variations of the code, by putting the "test" text before the `\center`command and by enclosing `\center` within `{}` (which, strangely, makes the "test" text left justified). What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

PS: I am using the `bookest` document class and the `graphicx`, `float` and `wrapfig` packages. I havent posted the preamble because I dont know if its relevant, but can do so if asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{merit_order}\\
\hfill\small test \cite{_some_citation_}    
\caption{Merit-order of generating plants} \label{fig:meritorder}  
\end{figure}
```

Comment: thanks! just so I know, is `\hfill` the only (or easiest) way? More generally, do `\raggedleft` and such not work within `float` environments?

Comment: sure, it works too. But `\hfill` is easier in this case. For `\raggedleft` you have to use a paragraph